# deselectRowAtIndexPath - Was it needed?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I was following this tutorial: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/ThirdTutorial.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011343-CH10-SW1,
where you have a table view.
The table view has Dynamic prototype cells.
During the tutorial, I selected a cell *on storyboard*, and set the 'Selection' type to: none.
But in the final part of the tutorial, still we were told to add

```
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
```

line inside the

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

method.

For me this seemed redundant, due to the 'Selection´ is *none* which I did as above.
Or I am wrong? Since I selected *none* as Selection in storyboard(for a cell), why do we need that *deselect* method? The cell won't be higlighted anyway, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The row is still selected. The style of 'none' only relates to how it looks when selected.

So yes, you need to deselect the row when you are done with it.

Comment: hm.. fine So the storyboard option was for only visual state? Ok, it seemed weird just since, I track selection/deselection state of items in a custom way (the objects in the table view are custom type and have their own selection state, especially that's why I thought why would one need to deselect some standard "state" of the table view cell)

Comment: The table view tracks the last selected row (or multiple if you enable multi-select). So you should deselect the last selected row when you don't need to track the selection any more. This is independent of the selection style.

Comment: Imagine an audio player where you select the cell with the song, and the song is kept playing (selected), until you tap something else. In the end, it's only a matter to allow for more customization on a `UITableView`

Comment: @rmaddy: I have problem putting this down. I am following selection state of objects in table view in a manual way. The objects in the Table view are of custom class and have custom property which states whether they are selected or not. So, that's why I thought why one would need to track some "standard" property of a Table View cell using the _deselect_ method...

Comment: That's all fine. I your case, deselecting the tow is probably optional. Is just common practice, in most cases, to deselect a row after it is selected.

Comment: @rmaddy: Yes actually because I commented the line with _deselect_ method and table view still works as expected ...

Answer (score 0):

Changing the "Selection" setting in storyboard changes the way that the cell looks when selected. (Thank you rmaddy, that was my mistake)

The line in didSelectRowAtIndexPath will perform some operation when a specific row is tapped, and then removes the selected graphic from the cell that was just tapped.

Comment: The selection setting defines how a cell looks when selected.